# Best way to create image segmentation dataset to read in with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to segment a bunch of images, and therefore have to train some classifier.
For that I have to create groundtruths of my image.
So far I did it like this:

1. Segment the image in gimp with the magnetic scissor
2. Fill the three different segments of the image with plain green/red/blue
3. Import the image as an array with numpy
4. Since at the edges between two different classes there is a transition between the two colors, I use clustering to summarize the pixel in three classes

Is there a better/more direct way to do this?
(Note: I dont want to use a pre segmented dataset, I want to create my own one)

Comment: I think this looks like a totally reasonable way of doing it, at least if you are doing this on small scale. You could also use the transition on the edges to get so called fuzzy segmentation (i.e. 50% class A, 50% class B).